# How can we put our reputation score as image in about me

Tags: support, reputation

I don't know weather i have to ask this question here or somewhere else because i am pretty new in metastackoverflow.

Is it possible to put our reputation score as image like below in about me page, i have seen some people have done this but i don't know how to do this. If anyone have any idea then please tell me the steps.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Yes; http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Comment: @AmalMurali, Thankyou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It is known as [User Flair™](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair). Go to that page, copy the HTML code, and add it in your profile. Alternatively, you can simply add the following snippet:

```
![](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/<USERID>.png)
```

in your profile. For [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), the user flair image would look like:

> [image]

Note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.